# Raspberry Pi and Amazon Cloud Drive, is that possible?

Tags: backup

I have a rpi connected to my Apple Airport Extreme, where I plugged an external USB hard drive. Today I'm running a backup service from CrashPlan to basically backup almost 2TB of photos and documents.

I was wondering if there's some way to rsync (or any other type of sync) those files to Amazon Cloud Drive, using the raspberry pi.

The reason I wish to change from CrashPlan to CloudDrive is that crashplan view of backuped files is confuse and I really don't trust them, and with Cloud Drive I would be able to access some of those bkpd files over my smartphone and computers.

So, anyone know some way to achieve this?

Comment: Still work in progress https://github.com/sgeb/acdcli

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by "Cloud Drive". I have a Debian linux t1.micro instance (virtual host) on Amazon's EC cloud. I can use rsync or unison to back files up to that just like any other *nix host. If you mean directly using Amazon's S3 storage services, you should be able to build something using [Amazon's AWS CLI tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). I haven't done this yet myself.

I had a bad experience with CrashPlan as well, and only trust solutions I have full control over now.

Comment: Cloud Drive is a service from Amazon, it's like Dropbox, but way more cheaper and foccused on what I really need, photo storage… you can see more about Amazon Cloud Drive here: https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/home

Comment: Not aware of a linux client for that service, much less a RPi-compatible solution. S3 might be useful _instead_ of Cloud Drive but at 2 TB, it sounds like you want to test what they mean by "unlimited".

Comment: there isn't a official client for linux, I was hopping to see someone hacking it, and them make something like on my RPi. They have an app API, I'll probably look on it and if I find something worth coding I get back here with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself yet, but I found a program that's available to 32bit ARM Linux, so it should run on the Raspberry Pi as well.

http://rclone.org/